# Cómo interactúa Fragment Activity con un Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una app para Android en JAVA que contiene tres fragments. La app consta de una **MainActivity que hereda de FragmentActivity**, y los fragments los añado mediante un **ScreenSlidePagerAdapter que hereda de FragmentStateAdapter**. Para las vistas utilizo un **ViewPager2**.

Al compilar la app y ejecutarla en una tablet **todo funciona perfectamente**, pero ahora, **me gustaría añadir un cronómetro en el uno de los tres fragmeents** (en concreto en el ScoreFragment), y este cronómetro me gustaría **iniciarlo o pararlo desde la MainActivity.**

El problema es que he leído la doc de google sobre como una Activity interactúa con sus fragments y he leido también varios ejemplos de la web, pero parece que todo se basan en FragmentPagerAdapters y no logro hacerlo funcionar (o estoy haciendo además algo más). Por esto necesito vuetras ayuda. Os adjunto mi código más abajo.

La pregunta es, **¿cómo la MainActivity debe interactuar con el fragment para que pueda usar los métodos public void start_chronometer(void) y  public void stop_chronometer(void)?**

**ScoreFragment**

```
public class ScoreFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_COUNT = "param1";

Chronometer mChronometer;

public ScoreFragment(){
}

public static ScoreFragment newInstance(Integer counter) {
    ScoreFragment fragment = new ScoreFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_COUNT, counter);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fragment_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scorefragment, container, false);

    // Chronometer
    mChronometer = fragment_view.findViewById(R.id.Chronometer);
    //mChronometer = new Chronometer(this);
    mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return fragment_view;
}

public void start_chronometer(void){
    mChronometer.start();
}

public void stop_chronometer(void){
    mChronometer.stop();
}
}
```

**Main activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

/*** Fragments ***/
// Fragment mScoreFragment;

/*** GUI ***/
TabLayout tabLayout;
FloatingActionButton fab;

/**
 * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
 */
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;

/**
 * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
 * and next wizard steps.
 */
private ViewPager2 viewPager;


/**
 * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
 */
private FragmentStateAdapter pagerAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager2 and a PagerAdapter.
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
            new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
                @Override public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                    switch(position){
                        case 0: tab.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_score));
                            break;
                        case 1:tab.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_statistics));
                            break;
                        case 2:tab.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_about));
                            break;
                    }
                    //tab.setText("Tab " + (position + 1));
                }
            }).attach();

    // Floating Action Button
    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, R.string.tutorial_connect, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            scanLeDevice(true);
        }
    });

    Fragment scorefragment = pagerAdapter.createFragment(0);
    scorefragment.start
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
        // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}

/**
 * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects, in
 * sequence.
 */
public static class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fa) {
        super(fa);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                return ScoreFragment.newInstance(0);
            case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                return StatisticsFragment.newInstance(1);
            case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                return AboutFragment.newInstance(2);
            default:
                return null;
        }
        //return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

    public void start_chronometer(void){

    }

}
```

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: los métodos los quieres en la Activity y el cronómetro en el layout del fragment?

Comment: Para poder interactuar con el cronómetro del fragment desde la activity, puedes crear un viewmodel compartido entre ambos con los métodos play, pause y stop.  El viewmodel puede crear tres livedata que representen esos estados y que son observados por el fragment.  De esta manera si pulsa alguna acción desde la activity, llamas al viewmodel y el viewmodel se lo notifica al fragment que reaccionará a la acción.